# Laravel on sorting related model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I know from laravel documentation that I can do eager loading like:

```
$records = (new Route)->with('country')->get();
```

But when I execute this:

```
    $records = (new Route)->query()->with('country')->orderBy('country.name', 'asc')->paginate();
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country.name' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `routes` order by `country`.`name` asc limit 2 offset 0)
```

How I can sort on related model ?
How can I force laravel to load joined tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

```
$records = (new Route)->query()->join('countries', 'routes.country_id', '=', 'countries.id');
```

But is not ideal because joining are performed manualy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with eager loading :

```
$records = (new Route)->with(['country' => function ($q) {
                     $q->orderBy('name', 'asc');
                  }])->get(); // or paginate or whatever
```